# How to use the `mean_se()` function to calculate confidence intervals?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to programmatically create 95% confidence intervals. How can I set the `mult` argument of `mean_se` in `geom_errorbar()`?

```r
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), hp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  geom_errorbar(stat = "summary", width = .3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start

```r
library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), hp)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = "mean_se",
    fun.args = list(mult = 1.96),
    geom = "errorbar",
    width = 0.3
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>